# How to set a doskey for the doskey command?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

If I do "doskey alias=doskey" then do "doskey /macros" it will list alias=doskey under the macros, however if I try to use it, ex "alias clear=cls" it doesn't work.

How do I set a doskey for the doskey command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Unix shell aliases, DOSKEY macros do not automatically preserve the remaining command-line arguments – you need to specify `$*` at the end of every macro:

```
doskey alias=doskey $*
```